How to remove next-auth callbackUrl and error query parameter from url
I'm working with Nuxt and I'm trying to implement Credentials provider authentication with next-auth (version 4.21.1) and @sidebase/nuxt-auth (version 0.7.2). I setup a custom sign-in page and I got a callbackUrl and error query parameters once the page is loaded (before signin) which I would like to hide from the user.
For example
http://localhost:3000/_auth?callbackUrl=http://localhost:3000/&error=undefined

On the Nitro server side I have the auth handler under /server/api/[...].ts
export default NuxtAuthHandler({
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: '/_auth',
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider.default({
      async authorize(credentials: any) {
        ...
      }
    }),

Auth configuration in nuxt.config.ts
{ 
  auth: {
    baseURL: `/api/_auth`,
    provider: {
      type: 'authjs',
    },
    globalAppMiddleware: {
      isEnabled: true,
    },
    session: {
      enableRefreshPeriodically: false,
      enableRefreshOnWindowFocus: true,
    }
  }
}

Any idea how I can remove those query parameters?
